# Understanding a traceback error

Tags: python, assertion, traceback

I am trying to understand a traceback error that I am receiving. See below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 291, in test_cache_in_function
    self.assertTrue("sunset" in testfilestr,"Testing that the sunset request was cached")
AssertionError: Testing that the sunset request was cached
```

Does the above error mean that "sunset" should not be in the cached file?

Comment: it means that the string "sunset" is not present in `testfilestr` so the `assertTrue` fails.

Comment: yes. why don't you print the string?

Comment: Take a look at that initial try-catch block. There are two variable names floating around: `saved_cache` and `CACHE_DICTION`. I am going to guess that only the second one is correct.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to post a minimal code example which reproduces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point about nomenclature. You are getting a `AssertionError`. The error is printed along with the traceback, which indicates the sequence of calls that led to that error.

In your particular case, it looks like the error is caused because the assertion made by `self.assertTrue(...)` came out `False`. You are asserting that the string `"sunset"` is in `testfilestr`, but it is not. Probably because it is in the cache file instead.

The second argument to `assertTrue` is a message, which you see as the message to the `AssertionError`. This argument is optional, and is usually used to clarify the error beyond the obvious default message, which would be something to the effect of `"sunset" in testfilestr is False, expected True`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Your explanation makes sense, I edited my topic and added my full code, if you could take a look that would be great!

Comment: That is clearly not the entire code since it gives me no information about how you call the function.

Comment: it should all be there now!

Comment: I can't help you fix an exception if I don't see the code that raises the exception. The function you are using to test is all fine and dandy, but I have no idea how you set things up, what you pass in when you call it or what happens to the return value.